# Proving that opposite of a opposite category is equal to itself

Tags: category-theory

I am new to category theory. While I was reading the Wikipedia article about [opposite category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_category), I am stuck with this statement:

> Doing the reversal twice yields the original category, so the opposite of an opposite category is the original category itself. In symbols, $(\mathcal C^{op})^{op} = \mathcal C$.

How can we prove that $(\mathcal C^{op})^{op} = \mathcal C$? The following is what I have done so far.

1. Since $obj(\mathcal C^{op}) = obj(\mathcal C)$, we obtain $obj((\mathcal C^{op})^{op}) =obj(\mathcal C)$.
2. For every $x,y \in \mathcal C$, $\mathcal C(x,y) = \mathcal C^{op}(y,x) = (\mathcal C^{op})^{op}(x,y)$, thus $mor(\mathcal C) = mor((\mathcal C^{op})^{op})$.

**How can we conclude that $(\mathcal C^{op})^{op} = \mathcal C$ using only above two arguments**
(equality between class of objects and morphisms between $\mathcal C$ and $(\mathcal C^{op})^{op} $)?

Comment: Seems to me like you're done.

Comment: @AlexProvost Thanks for the comment. Is this related to our definition of category? Since  definition of category involves "class" (in set theory), I can conclude that above arguments show equality between objects and morphisms (as elements of class, which are sets).

Comment: Hm, this seems like a natural question to ask in this context because one has to abandon sets.  I think that membership is still a valid thing to use for classes, and therefore so is equality of classes, but that membership is not governed by the additional restrictions we usually put on the ZFC membership relation.